# Python Pandas - Dataframe column - Convert FY in format '2015/2016' to '15/16'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe (call it 'FY') which has financial year values in the format: `2015/2016` or `2016/2017`.

I want to convert the whole column so it says `15/16` or `16/17` etc instead.

I presume you somehow only take the 3rd, 4th and 5th character from the string, as well as the 8th and 9th, but haven't got a clue how to do it.

Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a string `date = "2015/2016"` you could do the following to get `15/16`:

1. Use `left, right = date.split('/')` to capture both separate dates
2. Remove all but last 2 characters from string with:

   ```
   new_left = left[-2:]
   new_right = right[-2:]
   ```
3. Join the new string into one with `new_date = new_left+'/'+new_right`

**Edit**: A one liner solution working directly with the dataframe, based on other answers:

```
df['new'] = df['fy'].str.split('/')[0][-2:] +'/'+ df['fy'].str.split('/')[1][-2:]
```

This is a more generic approach as it will work for strings with different lengths and obtain only the last 2 characters, preventing error from incorrect indexes and preventing you from hard-coding them (even though your dates will probably always have 4 chars each plus the '/', at least in the next 8,000 years)

Comment: Thank you so much. Works exactly as you said. I have upvoted. I hope you dont mind but I am going to accept Andrew's answer as I think it would help other people more only because it does it all in one line

Comment: Ok, clad I could help, however that answer will not work if somehow your string had different length, as the indexes will be offset or incorrect. This approach is more generic one

Comment: Expanded my answer based on your feedback and other answers

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out of your day to help.

Comment: No problem @ScoutEU ;) it is always a pleasure to help others. That is the way of SO. You never know when a "random stranger" will make your day. Good luck with your coding

Comment: Thank you. If you had not noticed, I marked your answer as the accepted answer. If you are near the UK, have a great evening. If you are more US based, have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way using this sample dataset:

```
df
          fy
0  2015/2016
1  2016/2017
2  2017/2018

df['fy_new'] = df['fy'].str[2:4] + '/' + df['fy'].str[7:9]
df
          fy fy_new
0  2015/2016  15/16
1  2016/2017  16/17
2  2017/2018  17/18
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked exactly as I wanted! :)

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**
Use `pd.Series.str.replace`

```
df.FY.str.replace('\d{2}(\d{2}/)\d{2}(\d{2})', r'\1\2')

0    15/16
1    16/17
Name: FY, dtype: object
```

---

**Option 2**
Use `pd.DataFrame.replace`

```
df.replace(dict(FY={'\d{2}(\d{2}/)\d{2}(\d{2})': r'\1\2'}), regex=True)

      FY
0  15/16
1  16/17
```

Comment: A lot of great answers here, thank you VERY much for your help. I have already marked Andrews answer as the accepted answer, but really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @ScoutEU Thanks for the comment.  Keep in mind, your choice of accepted answer should be about what you think is most useful.  But it's your choice... Glad I could help.

Comment: Good point. I will wait until the post is older before marking. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string you can always just choose parts of it by writing:

foo = 'abcdefg'

foo2 = foo[2:4]

print foo2

then the output would be:
cd

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    s = rows["FY"]   
    df.loc[index, "FY"] = "".join(s[2:5] + s[7:])
```

Here `df` is the dataframe object.

Comment: Hey, tried yours first as it does it all in one go. Whilst I dont get any errors, it also doesnt do anything? 

for index, rows in time1.iterrows():
    s = rows['Date FY']   
    time1.loc[index, 'Date FY'] == "".join(s[2:5] + s[7:])

Comment: Try it again. I updated the code. I inserted `==` instead of `=`

Comment: Perfect! :D!  ty!